# Distance traveled by a bouncing ball with exponentially diminishing rebounds

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is kind of an odd question, but can somebody please tell me that I am crazy with the following question, I did the math, and what I am told to prove is simply wrong:

Question:
Show that a ball dropped from height of *h* feet and bounces in such a way that each bounce is $\frac34$ of the height of the bounce before travels a total distance of 7 *h* feet.

My Work:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} h \left(\frac34\right)^n = 4h$$

Obviously 4 *h* does not equal 7 *h* .  What does the community get?

I know that my calculations are correct, see Wolfram Alpha and it confirms my calculations, that only leaves my formula, or the teacher being incorrect...

Edit:
Thanks everyone for pointing out my flaw, it should be something like:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} -h + 2h \left(\frac34\right)^n = 7h$$

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: sigma-algebra is something different than using $\sum$...

Comment: Thanks, again, I got the whole n00b thing going on ;)

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty h=\infty$; you want to switch the summation and the (-h+) in your last formula.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that when the ball bounces it goes both up and down. So from the second term onwards, you need to count each term twice. Therefore the answer is $2 \cdot 4h - h = 7h$ ($h$ is the first term, which is only counted once).

Comment: BINGO! Thanks Yuval and Brandon, this is really an awesome site; how did they manage to get so many rocket scientists on here?

Comment: @Nitroware: I don't think this is rocket science... ;-)

Comment: It's not rocket surgery either. ;)

Answer (score 13):

Hint: You are forgetting to count the distance traveled on the way up from the bounce. If the initial drop is from height $h$, the ball bounces up $\frac{3h}{4}$ and then drops from the same distance, and so on.

Answer (score 7):

Your computation does not give the *total distance traveled*, it only gives the distance it traveled *downward.*

The ball first falls $h$. Then it *rises* $\frac{3}{4}h$, and falls $\frac{3}{4}h$ again; then it *rises* $(\frac{3}{4})^2h$, and falls that much again. Etc.

So the total distance traveled by the ball is 
$$h + 2h\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) + 2h\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 + \cdots = h + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3h}{2}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-1}.$$

This gives, by the usual formula, a total distance of:
$$ h + \frac{\quad\frac{3h}{2}\quad}{1 - \frac{3}{4}} = h + \frac{\quad\frac{3h}{2}\quad}{\frac{1}{4}} = h + \frac{12h}{2} = 7h.$$

Answer (score 5):

To get symmetry - a complete sawtooth pattern - suppose the ball is first thrown up from ground to height $h$. The total distance $x$ is that of the first tooth $= 2h$ plus the remaining sawtooth $= 3/4\ x$. Thus $x =\: 2h + 3/4\ x,\ $ so $x = 8h\:.\ $ Subtracting the intitial throw up leaves $7h.$

Comment: @Bill: at first sight this looks very elegant because it seems to avoid the use of geometric series. However, I wonder how to make the observation 'the remaining sawtooth = $3/4 x$' rigourous without resorting to geometric series after all.

Comment: @wil Indeed, there are various ways to make the argument rogorous, depending on the OP's background. But my goal was to encourage students to think about the innate symmetry, here the *shift* that arises by mutiplication by $3/4\:.\:$ *Shift* symmetries are ubiquitous so, it lends insight to bring them to the fore when they play fundamental roles.

Comment: Ok, so then you're actually rederiving the geometric series using the shift argument: $S=\sum_k r^k\Rightarrow S-rS= 1\Rightarrow S=\frac{1}{1-r}$.

Comment: @Wil That's one way to view it. But rather than teaching students to be able to rotely sum geometric series, I prefer to teach them the essence of the matter, here the innate shift symmetry. Exploiting innate symmetries is a fundamental mathematical problem-solving technique. So I alway try to encourage viewpoints that help to develop intuition for such.

Comment: @Bill: I appreciate your didactical ideas!

Comment: @Wil Alas, this is not the most interesting example for advancing such points. For some better examples see some of my other posts exploiting [innate symmetries.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+innate)

Answer (score 4):

Before jumping to a formula, let us calculate a little.  The distance travelled until the first contact with the ground is $h$.

The distance travelled between the first contact and the second is $(h)(2)(3/4)$
(up and then down).  The distance travelled from second contact to third is $(h)(2)(3/4)^2$, and so on.

So the total distance travelled is
$$h+(h)(2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$$

Finally, sum the infinite series.  That sum is $3$, giving a total of $7h$.